# How to arrange the key in this plot?

Tags: pgfplots, plot, gnuplot

basically I have plot like this:

[image]

It looks bad because two reasons:

1. The middle figure, five keys are overlapped with lines
2. The 6 key in the third figure, even they are not overlapped, they are not horizontal, which is inconsistent with the above two figures.

I am tried to put the keys to outside the figure, say:

```
set key outside
```

However, as essentially I am writing a double-column paper (these figures are in one column), it makes the figures become too small...

[image]

I tried to manipulate the

```
set size ratio 0.35
```

But didn't get some good results.

I just want to represent the figure clear enough, while keeping these keys. Any though on how to do it?

I simplified my `gnuplot` script and copied it here:

```
set term pdf size 8,10 font "Arial,24"
set output "test.pdf"
set multiplot layout 3,1
set size ratio 0.35
set datafile separator ","
set offset 0, 0, 0, 0
set xtics norangelimit
set ytics nomirror
set termoption dashed
set key bottom right
set key horiz
set yrange [-5:1000]
set style data linespoints
set key vertical maxrows 5
plot 'plot/data.csv' using 1:xtic((int($0)%4)==0?sprintf("%d", $0*50):"") title   columnheader(1) pt 4 lw 1, \
'' using 2 title columnheader(2) pt 5 lw 4 ps .8 lc rgb "#4169E1", \
'' using 3 title columnheader(3) pt 6 lw 4 ps .8 lc rgb "#DAA520", \
'' using 4 title columnheader(4) pt 7 lw 4 ps .8 lc rgb "#FF7F50", \
'' using 5 title columnheader(5) pt 8 lw 4 ps .8 lc 7
plot 'plot/data.csv' using 6:xtic((int($0)%4)==0?sprintf("%d", $0*50):"") title columnheader(6) pt 4 lw 1, \
'' using 7 title columnheader(7) pt 5 lw 4 ps .8 lc rgb "#4169E1", \
'' using 8 title columnheader(8) pt 6 lw 4 ps .8 lc rgb "#DAA520", \
'' using 9 title columnheader(9) pt 7 lw 4 ps .8 lc rgb "#FF7F50", \
'' using 10 title columnheader(10) pt 8 lw 4 ps .8 lc 7
plot 'plot/data.csv' using 11:xtic((int($0)%4)==0?sprintf("%d", $0*50):"") title columnheader(11) pt 4 lw 1, \
'' using 12 title columnheader(12) pt 5 lw 4 ps .8 lc rgb "#4169E1", \
'' using 13 title columnheader(13) pt 6 lw 4 ps .8 lc rgb "#DAA520", \
'' using 14 title columnheader(14) pt 7 lw 4 ps .8 lc rgb "#FF7F50", \
'' using 15 title columnheader(15) pt 8 lw 4 ps .8 lc 7, \
'' using 16 title columnheader(16) pt 9 lw 4 ps .8 lc rgb "#7FFFD4"
```

I upload the data to my dropbox [account](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jqcx2g4nc8grj8g/data.csv?dl=0). and shared it to the public.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) along with your full gnuplot code.

Comment: @HarishKumar, OK, but it contains a large amount of data, in `csv` format.. How can I upload it..? Sorry this is the first time I use this `tex` site.

Comment: Use `filecontents` and reduce the amount of data. If not possible, at least provide code. Data we can simulate.

Comment: @HarishKumar, done! Hope it works!

Comment: How is this related to TeX? This appears to be a gnuplot question. Are you using something like `pgfplots`, or just including the gnuplot result?

Comment: @erik, hmm.. well, I use `gnuplot` to draw and include the results as a pdf in my `tex` code.

Comment: But your question isn't about the TeX part, its about the gnuplot part. I'd say this is at risk of being closed as off-topic.

Comment: Now my next query is, if we use `pgfplots` on the outer layer, will that be acceptable?

Comment: @HarishKumar, Yes! As long as the output looks good !

Comment: @computereasy: I have added an answer with `pgfplots`. Hope that will be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some how I was not able to get your gnuplot code to get working. I didn't want to use your data here. Hence the following should give you some idea and serve as a starting point.

This approach uses `pgfplots` on the outer layer with `raw gnuplot` option and the gnuplot code is used inside for plotting the actual graph. Hence the legend position can be controlled by `pgfplots`. The normal way of doing this is by using

```
legend style={at={(.5,0.9)},anchor=north},
```

where the parameters are changed at will. Another way is to name the legends and use `\ref`. The following code uses this approach. Additionally you can change the number of columns using

```
legend columns=4
```

and change the width using `width` key.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
\begin{axis}[
width=0.8\linewidth,   %% adjust
xmin = 0,
xmax = 1.5,
ymin = 0,
ymax = 6.2831853072,
xlabel={$x$},
ylabel={$y$},
legend columns=2,   %%<---      change this to suit
legend to name=mylegend,
%legend style={at={(.5,0.9)},anchor=north},    %%<-- you can use this too if you want
]

\addplot +[no markers,
raw gnuplot,
thick,
blue,
] gnuplot {
    set contour base;
    set cntrparam levels discrete 0.003;
    unset surface;
    set view map;
    set isosamples 500;
    plot [0:2*pi] 5*sin(x);
};
\addlegendentry{some}
\addplot +[no markers,
raw gnuplot,
thick,
green,
] gnuplot {
    set contour base;
    set cntrparam levels discrete 0.003;
    unset surface;
    set view map;
    set isosamples 500;
    plot [0:2*pi] 3*sin(x);
};
\addlegendentry{some}
\addplot +[no markers,
raw gnuplot,
thick,
red,
] gnuplot {
    set contour base;
    set cntrparam levels discrete 0.003;
    unset surface;
    set view map;
    set isosamples 500;
    plot [0:2*pi] 2*sin(x);
};
\addlegendentry{some}
\addlegendentry{some}
\addplot +[no markers,
raw gnuplot,
thick,
orange,
] gnuplot {
    set contour base;
    set cntrparam levels discrete 0.003;
    unset surface;
    set view map;
    set isosamples 500;
    plot [0:2*pi] 2*sin(x);
};
\addlegendentry{some}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%%If you put \centering at the beginning and put a \par here the legends come to bottom of plot
\ref{mylegend}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or... you may use only `pgfplots` for the entire graph.